# Emacs for Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: mac, emacs

I am trying to work with the latest version of Gnu Emacs on my Mac.

I installed emacs (`install emacs`) using MacPorts and it is working but without the GUI ... Is there a special thing to install (like an another port including the gui) or a special command to launch it properly ?

I also tried the same under X11 without success.

If it is not possible to make it work like that, is there another way ? I read about Aquamacs but apparently it is not a port of Gnu Emacs, but it is just loosely based on Gnu Emacs.'

Any help and advices are welcome !

Thanks (and I hope my question is clear enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you build it with the `+gtk` variant? Use `port info emacs` and `port variants emacs` to see that there is a gtk and motif variant that provide a GUI through X11. Also check out the emacs-app port, which is an OS X Cocoa version.

Comment: Thanks ! In the `info` of `emacs-app` they say "It differs from Carbon ports of GNU Emacs in that it makes a more concerted attempt from the ground up to follow OS X desktop and UI conventions." Ok; but which one is the Carbon one ?

Comment: @Cedric Not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't really call Aquamacs a port of GNU/emacs ... it's just simply an extension of it to make it more Mac like -- it is still very much emacs.

That having been said, you can get a perfectly "clean" build of emacs 23.2 without going through here:

http://emacsforosx.com/

You'll get an Emacs.app which you would use like any other application, but it's pure, 100% emacs.

Comment: OK, Thanks ! I tried this .app and finally I also managed to have it with Mac Port.